# What is a good choice of Pistol as a Sniper?

Tags: warframe

I am playing [Volt](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Volt_%28Warframe%29) and recently replaced my starting melee and rifle with [Dual Ether](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Dual_Ether) and [Snipetron](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Snipetron).

What would be a good choice for Pistol to complement my choice of Rifle/Melee weapon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a sniper as a main weapon, go for the dual vipers (just released) as a pistol. They have a rapid fire which would help you get out of close situations that a snipetron could not accurately handle. Only problem is, dual vipers burn ammo quick, but nothing a few mods can't fix!

Comment: My first viper will be ready in 7h! :D so on my way to getting Twin Vipers :)

Answer (score 2):

Ballistica is great for ranged combat and is easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

In the current game, only two pistols truly stand out for long-range sniping.

The first is the [Marelok](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Marelok). Considered by many to a "long-range" Brakk (a very highly-efficient Pistol for CQC), it is by essence a "sniping" pistol.

Since it's base damage is 159, easily boosted with Hornet Strike and other mods, you have what is in essence a sniping pistol.

The second that is somewhat used, not as often, is the Lex Prime.  It has huge Puncture damage, the only drawback being that not many people have it (must farm the Void for parts).